# Flutter use of animatedswitcher is not triggering (Edited)

Tags: animation, flutter, dart, flutter-animation

However the initial animation is seen and others like scale. Am I able to chain or is it recommended I just break up into separate widgets?

The Initial Opacity and Transform Widgets trigger animations just fine it's however the AnimatedSwitcher that doesn't seem to work although it does with the ScaleTransition Widget.

```
Opacity(
                opacity: animation.textOpacity.value,
                child: Transform(
                  transform: new Matrix4.translationValues(
                      animation.xTranslationRightLeft.value, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                    transitionBuilder:
                        (Widget child, Animation<double> offsetanimation) {
                      return SlideTransition(
                        child: child,
                        position: animation.yTranslationUpDown2,
                      );
                    },
                    switchInCurve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                    child: Row(
                        key: ValueKey<int>(newUser.registerStep),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          (() {
                            if (newUser.registerStep <= 1) {
                              return Text(
                                'First things first,\nchoose your\nusername..',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 36),
                              );
                            } else if (newUser.registerStep == 2) {
                              return Text(
                                'Next,\nCreate a\nPassword.',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 36),
                              );
                            } else if (newUser.registerStep == 3) {
                              return Text(
                                'We need to\nknow a little\nabout you.',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 36),
                              );
                            }
                          })()
                        ]),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 700),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```